# Good practice at end of Dockerfile?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

I am wondering what is good practice to have at the end of a Dockerfile? I was thinking one of the three (or maybe all three?)?

- apt-get clean
- apt-get autoclean
- apt-get autoremove

Answer (score 0):

`RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*`

Once your image is mostly finalized and you know what's going into it, the utility of `autoclean` and `autoremove` is pretty much nil.